# Formatting data in a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I am fairly new to python and I am creating a program to try and take data from a text file, The quiz has 10 questions, and the name and scores of the users are saved in a text file. This is what the text file looks like:

Bob - 7 
Steve - 4 
Jake - 10

The idea is if the person tries again and gets another score, the program will realise the user already has data in the file, and it will be appended as such:

Bob - 7, 8, 3

The user can only save a maximum of 3 scores, e.g. If Bob tries again and gets a 10, the 7 will be removed and the 8 and 3 move one place forward like this:

Bob - 8, 3, 10

Then as an option, all the names and scores need to be read back in and placed in order of score with their names attached, If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import random, time, re

name = input("Welcome, please type your name to continue:  ")

class_number = input("What class are you in? (1, 2 or 3)")
class_number = ("H:\A453\\Class_"+class_number+".txt")

print("\nThank you", name, "you will now answer a short series of               questions..\n")

score_counter = 0

x = 1
```

The Questions come here.... score_counter + 1 if correct etc..

```
f = open(class_number,"r")
contents = f.read()

items = re.findall(str(name+".*$"),contents,re.MULTILINE)
for y in items:
username, score = y.split(' - ')
print(username, score)
```

The part that adds the score to the database is here, but I have omitted it as I have yet to complete the bit above ^

```
f = open(class_number,"r")
f.write(str(name)+" - "+str(score_counter))
f.close()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, also I am not sure how to fix the problem of if for instance the user's name is Bob, and in the text file there is:

Bobby - 9

It will pull up Bobby's score instead, a fix for this would also be great.

Jake

Comment: Not answering your question per se, but have you thought about serializing your initial dataset into something else than a text file, say, JSON or something that's somewhat more machine friendly? :) And adding some extra methods to print scorecards in a human-readable format.

Comment: He might not be in control of the input.  I think a dictionary would be fine for tracking the data.  {username : [list_of_scores]}